# Django-simple-history error setting ChangeReason

Tags: python, django, django-simple-history

I am using Django-simple-history version 2.3.0 with Django 2.0 and Python 3.6.

I am comparing the previously existing data with the new data(comparing to serializer.validated_data) that is received via PUT request, comparing fields and making a list of changes.

I am trying to add this list to my changeReason.

My first attempt of saving the serializer and then calling an update results in 2 entry in the database.

I tried to follow the docs and set as suggested there, but I get the following errors:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'history_change_reason'
```

when I try to pass the changeReason explicitly using update_change_reason

or

```
AttributeError: 'PatientSerializer' object has no attribute 'id'
```

when I try it implicitly.

My question:

How do I update the changeReason and also have only 1 entry in the database.

Here is my code for the View:

```
class PutDetailsView(APIView):
"""
    View used sending response for successful patient update
"""
permission_classes = [
    permissions.IsAuthenticated
]
serializer_class = PatientSerializer

def put(self, request):
    is_many = True if isinstance(request.data, list) else False
    try:
        patient = Patient.objects.get(pk=request.data['ID'])
    except Patient.DoesNotExist:
        return Response({"status": 0, "error": "Patient does not exist"}, status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
    serializer = PatientSerializer(patient, data=request.data, many=is_many)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        patient = Patient.objects.filter(pk=request.data['ID']).values()
        my_dict = {}
        for keys in patient:
            for key, value in keys.items():
                my_dict[key] = value
        new_data_dict = dict(serializer.validated_data)
        change_reason = []
        print(my_dict)
        print(new_data_dict)
        for items in new_data_dict:
            if new_data_dict[items] != my_dict[items]:
                field_changed = items + " changed from " + str(my_dict[items]) + " to " + \
                                str(new_data_dict[items])
                change_reason.append(field_changed)
            else:
                pass
        # I get error in this line
        serializer.changeReason = change_reason
        serializer.save()
        return Response({"status": 1, "message": "Details successfully updated"})
    return Response({"status": 0, "error": serializer.errors}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

I tried doing serializer.save() first then calling object and updating changeReason, but this results in 2 entries in the simple-history table for the Model. How do I do it with only 1 entry.

My Serializer:

```
class PatientSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
"""

    This class is used to serialize Patient model

"""

class Meta:
    model = Patient
    fields = '__all__'

def create(self, validated_data):
    end_session_obj = Patient.objects.create(
        **validated_data
    )
    return end_session_obj
```

Thanks.

P.S: This is my first post, please let me know if I have missed any information or provided incomplete info, I will update accordingly.

Comment: When you tried to use `update_change_reason`, it seems that you didn't actually pass an instance of `Patient` to that function. That error: 
> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'history_change_reason'
implies that an object without a model class was passed to the function. I would start there is a part of debugging.

Is the error you get in the code snippet you wrote this error: `AttributeError: 'PatientSerializer' object has no attribute 'id'`

Comment: When I pass the instance of the model, it results in 2 entries in my database.One for initial insertion, second with update.